# Creating dynamic map graphs

Tags: windows, software-rec, graphics

I need a software (or softwares) to achieve the following. I'm not sure if it could be done, but I'd like to hear the suggestions from super users.

The data I want to use for graphing purposes include sales figures of magazines by provinces. There are 81 provinces of Turkiye, and I want the computer to automatically paint / write on a graph according to the sales magnitude of the provinces. Since there are loads of magazines with loads of issues, the process must be executed automatically just after selecting the related magazine and issue. So there will be graphs showing the sales weight of the whole country with some nice illustrations. Those graphs might be used as part of some decision support mechanism to help field teams. This is a good example for what I'm after:

[image: Link]

Is it possible?

I have all the data and base maps of Turkiye to be filled/painted. I'm sure this is not easy. If there is a way to do that, it might probably include more than one software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to create a graph or a map?  If you're trying to do a map there are many good open source GIS software packages that will do what you want.  You can link the sales data to the region and can then display it graphically in the map.  This website has links to several desktop GIS softwares and has excellent resources to get you started.  www.osgeo.org  I would personally recommend looking at Quantum GIS. www.qgis.org

Comment: What I like to create is something like that: http://naraku.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/us-home-prices-and-usa-heat-map_july_7_2008.jpg

Comment: That is known as a choropleth map and is created by linking data to geographic features and then classifying the features based on a particular value or range of values.  GIS (Geographic Information Systems) software is going to be a easy way to create that.  The links in my previous post should get you started.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for showing the right direction.